# Twig variable in form_row(form.form, 'attr':{'value':var})

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I try make variable in form_row()

```
{{ form_start(genusForm) }}
{{ form_row(genusForm.speciesCount, {
'label': variable
}) }}
{{ form_end(genusForm) }}
```

I tried `{{ variable }`, won't work.

Comment: what if you do {{ dump(variable) }} right before generating the form? It has to be a string. And what happens when you do {% set variable = 'just testing' %} before generating the form? Probably the variable does not exist yet in the twig or does not contain a string

Answer (score 1):

**form_row** returns the label and the input and the error block
so you shoud use **form_label** if you want to add an attribute for the label

```
{{ form_label(genusForm.speciesCount, { 'attr': {'name-attr': variable}} ) }}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-label-view-label-variables